# how to add populated select field to form on button click

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have form where a user can select an option and then submit, i want to add a button that will add another select option to the form. so that the user can submit two or more options

```
<form action="#" method="get">
<button type="button" onclick="add_field()">Add another field</button>
<select>
{%for each in mechanic_list %}

  <option name="Mechanic_" value={{each.id}}>{{each.DESCRIPTION}}</option>

  {%endfor%}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>    
    function add_field() 
    {
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],
    input = document.createElement('select');

    input.setAttribute('type', 'select');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'pet');
    form.appendChild(input);
    };
    </script>
```

the above code will populate a first select box and has a button that adds empty select fields (after the submit, for some reason)

two questions
1. how do i populate the added select field 
2. how do i move the new field to the proper side of the submit button.

one thing to note, i am using the Django web Framework and have used a for loop to populate the select values.

this is a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5Jr8N/59/ (no for loop)

thanks

**Edit/update** 
HTML script as coded

```
<script>    
        function add_field() {
            var container = document.getElementById('selects'),
                input = document.createElement('select');
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            {% for each in mechanic_list %}
            opt.value = "{{each.id}}";
            opt.innerHTML = "{{each.DESCRIPTION}}";
            {%endfor%}
            input.appendChild(opt);
            input.setAttribute('type', 'select');
            input.setAttribute('name', 'pet');
            container.appendChild(input);
          };
    </script>
```

html script as "rendered" (given to browser/from browser "view source")

```
<script>    
        function add_field() {
            var container = document.getElementById('selects'),
                input = document.createElement('select');
            var opt = document.createElement("option");

            opt.value = "dd";
            opt.innerHTML = "dd";

            opt.value = "TT";
            opt.innerHTML = "Test for";

            input.appendChild(opt);
            input.setAttribute('type', 'select');
            input.setAttribute('name', 'pet');
            container.appendChild(input);
          };
    </script>
```

so this is working except that it only displays the last value not both/all values. this is so close i can taste it.

how do i get both/all the values not just the last one?

Comment: Keep in mind that your Django form class will also need the second field with all possible choices populated on the server-side, or your form will not be valid.

Comment: @Brandon This form is feeding a SOAP call so i am not using Django Forms for this particular one, if Django had a widget for this i would gladly set one up. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "populate the added select"?

To change position of new select field wrap existing `<select>` into `<span>` and append new selects to this `<span>`.  To populate options from original `<select>` just copy `innerHTML` from it:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
  <button type="button" onclick="add_field()">Add another field</button>
  <span id="selects">
    <select id="orig_select">
    {% for each in mechanic_list %}
      <option name="Mechanic_" value={{each.id}}>{{each.DESCRIPTION}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>    
    function add_field() {
      var container = document.getElementById('selects'),
          input = document.createElement('select');

      input.innerHTML = document.getElementById('orig_select').innerHTML;

      input.setAttribute('type', 'select');
      input.setAttribute('name', 'pet');
      container.appendChild(input);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: first off thank you for solving my placement issue second please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/5Jr8N/60/ the added select boxes have no values to select. they are blank. how do i add the values for the added select fields. thanks again.

Comment: Where you get values to populate added select box?

Comment: i am not sure of the term but Django lets me pass variables/data sets to the webpage/template. the 'for each in mechanic_list' loop populates the select values (at least the first one). i should be able to figure out how to pass the values i need if i can figure out how to it would populate a static list of options. the Jsfiddle in my first comment has a more traditional looking version (i'm doing the same thing just with a loop to add the select options). thanks for all of your help.

Comment: I added example to the answer. The question still: where you get this "some value"/"some text" data?

Comment: first off thank you for all of your help. I added some code to the original question that i hope will explain how i am getting the "some value"/"some text" that i need populated. all of your suggestions work wonderfully i just need to figure out how to add more than one select value. and i will be finished with this. thanks again.

Comment: If you want to copy options from original `<select>` to newly created one then you can copy `innerHTML` property. I edited the answer.